# AWS API Gateway acting as a proxy with certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I want to use the AWS API Gateway service as a http proxy and have control of the requests I make to a third party API.
This third party api needs a certificate to be able to make requests to it.
The problem comes when I make a request to the proxy, the request is done wrong.
The certificate I passed is not taken into account when it reaches the proxy and the request fails.
How can I make the certificate I pass in the request also redirect through the proxy?
I have tried many things, but can't find a solution that works for me.
Obviously, when I don't use the proxy, the requests work fine.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. I don't think AWS API Gateway was designed to be used this way.

Comment: @MarkB why? It can be used for proxy mode.